# Format <a> tag to Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I have a task where I need to format `div` data from html like this:

```
<div>
<h4>Some Title</h4>
<p><a href="somelink.com"><strong>Bold and then</strong> normal</a></p>
<p><a href="somelink2.com">Just normal</a></p>
</div>
```

To this:

```
#### Some Title
[**Bold and then** normal](somelink.com)  //two spaces after <a> tag for line breaks
[Just normal](somelink2.com)
```

I have function which replace all `<strong>` and `<em>` tags, but I dont know what to do with `<a>` tags in my case.

```
const toMarkdown = (text) => {
      let one = text.replace(/<em>/g,'*').replace(/<\/em>/g,'*');
      let two = one.replace(/<strong>/g,'**').replace(/<\/strong>/g,'**');
      return two
    }
```

```js
const html = `<div>
<h4>Some Title</h4>
<p><a href="somelink.com"><strong>Bold and then</strong> normal</a></p>
<p><a href="somelink2.com">Just normal</a></p>
</div>`

const toMarkdown = (text) => {
  let one = text.replace(/<em>/g, '*').replace(/<\/em>/g, '*');
  let two = one.replace(/<strong>/g, '**').replace(/<\/strong>/g, '**');
  return two
}

console.log(toMarkdown(html))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do  this

```js
const html = `<div><h4>Some Title</h4>
<p><a href="somelink.com"><strong>Bold and then</strong> normal</a> <em>bold</em></p>
<p><a href="somelink2.com">Just normal</a></p>
</div>`

const toMarkdown = (text) => {
  let obj = document.createElement("div");
  obj.innerHTML = text;
  [...obj.querySelectorAll("strong, em")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("*"+ele.textContent+"*"),ele));
  [...obj.querySelectorAll("a")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("["+ele.textContent+"]("+ele.href+")"),ele));
  [...obj.querySelectorAll("h4")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("####"+ele.textContent),ele));
  [...obj.querySelectorAll("p")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(ele.textContent),ele)); // ignore?
  [...obj.querySelectorAll("div")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(ele.textContent),ele));  
  
  return obj
}

console.log(toMarkdown(html).innerHTML)
```